# Batch removing the second sheet from many excel sheets in R?

Tags: r, excel, data-import

I have many excel sheets that I need to remove the second sheet before importing them. All files are .xlsx type in one folder and have same format. What kind of function should I use to achieve such?

Before removal, the 'remarks' sheet needs to be removed

[image: 1]

Wanted outcome: deleted sheet 'remarks'. need to loop it through all files in the folder

[image: 2]

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: By default, excel reading functions such as `readxl::read_excel()` only read in the first sheet, making it unnecessary to remove other sheets.

Comment: Hi Andrea, yes, that is true. I used Rio::import() function to read files. The issues with my files it needs to delete few lines and extract a few things and has been giving me error. I found the only way to prevent such is to delete the second sheet. That is why I am asking for ways to batch deleting the second sheet

Comment: Like @AndreaM says, you can tell which sheet to read `readxl::read_excel(path, sheet=1)`. Or `rio::import(file, sheet=1)`